# How insert Image that is located in my documents folder in a mail?

Tags: python, html, path, html-email, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email within the body an image that I located in this folder: `/Users/experiment/Documents/Opera Terza Gestionale/Opera_III_foto_concerto.jpg`

I'm using Python and pycharm, and this is the code, all works fine, but the image is not loaded, it every time looks like this in the body of my mail:
[image]

It doesn't work also if I put the image in the same directory of my main.py file (obviously calling `Opera_III_foto_concerto.jpg` and not the previous path).

Here is my code:

```
def sendEmail(receiverAddresses, subject, body, imageInBodyPath, signature, attachmentsPaths):
    message = EmailMessage()
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message['From'] = 'my_mail'
    message['To'] = receiverAddresses

    bodyImageFileName = ''
    if os.path.isfile(imageInBodyPath):
        with open(imageInBodyPath, 'rb') as bodyImageFile:
            bodyImageFileName = os.path.basename(bodyImageFile.name)
            bodyImageFileName = os.path.splitext(bodyImageFileName)[0]

    message.add_alternative("""\
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p style=\"color:black\"><strong>""" + body + """</strong></p>
            <img src=\"""" + imageInBodyPath + """\" alt=\"""" + bodyImageFileName + """"\">
            <p style=\"color:black\"><strong>""" + signature + """</strong></p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """, subtype='html')

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login('my_mail', 'my_password')
        smtp.send_message(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendEmail(receivers, 'oggetto', myBody, image_path, mySignature, paths)
```

Comment: Even though you specify a path in your computer, that path is not going to be accessible from your email client (for security reasons it has no access to your filesystem). You would have to send it as an attachment.

Comment: @dangom really thank you for your reply, there’s no Way to do this? When I send an email with Google mail it per mito me to add it insidie body of my mail…

Comment: See this example of how you can rework your code to send the files as attachment: https://gist.github.com/rdempsey/22afd43f8d777b78ef22 . You may be able to send it inside the body of the email, but in that case you'd have to upload the image to a server, and point your source to that URL instead. Try experimenting with setting the path to any `https://image/path.png` to see if that'd work. Google does that behind the scenes automatically for you. (so does stack overflow when you paste images into an answer - it generates a URL for them and puts that in the answer instead of your local path).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have locally referenced your image.

Upload your image to a publicly accessible server, and reference it in the code as e.g. https://via.placeholder.com/200x200 (you can use that src as a test if you like).

e.g. `<img src=\"https://www.myimages.com/images""" + bodyImageFileName + """\" ...>` (sorry if syntax is slightly wrong here - I'm not a python expert)

This will show the image inline (attaching an image is a different thing, and not what you want).

Comment: what if the image is dynamically changing? for eg, my code creates image then accesses it. I am trying to accomplish this by serving images using apache on specific port but it says it not found and I am able to access through src link

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani so can't you also dynamically create the link too? To fully explain you might need to ask a new question, unless you're using essentially the same code here

Comment: I see, I added a src link which replaces the images. It works fine now. Thank you for the comment.